# Android process lifecycle & services

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have been reading about process life-cycles after I noticed that android unexpectedly terminated my app. The app is normally running also in background but now it was terminated. The app listens gps location updates, battery state broadcasts, receives sms broadcasts, runs Bluetooth and tcp server etc. So it has quite a lot of jobs to do and until now it has succeeded pretty well.

What I found out was that android probably closed the process due to low RAM. My app was still in the 'app swap' list but when I selected it I noticed that it was actually restarted which explained the fact that I was not able to connect it earlier using tcp. Do you agree my conclusion or is there any other reason than low RAM that could cause this?

After reading a bit more I understood I should have implemented almost the whole application as a foreground service because those will be killed only after there are no normal activities to kill. However I'm not that comfortable in doing such a bit changes to the application at this point. BUT, then I found this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

> There are five levels in the importance hierarchy. The following list presents the different types of processes in order of importance (the first process is most important and is killed last):
>
> **Foreground process**
>
> A process that is required for what the user is currently doing. A process is considered to be in the foreground if any of the following conditions are true:
>
> -It hosts an Activity that the user is interacting with (the Activity's onResume() method has been called).
>
> -It hosts a Service that's bound to the activity that the user is interacting with.
>
> **-It hosts a Service that's running "in the foreground"—the service has called startForeground().**
>
> -It hosts a Service that's executing one of its lifecycle callbacks (onCreate(), onStart(), or onDestroy()).
>
> -It hosts a BroadcastReceiver that's executing its onReceive() method.

Please correct if I got the bolded condition wrong. Doesn't it mean that I could just make my app to host a dummy foreground service after which the process running my app and the dummy service would be considered as foreground process which again would mean that it would be very unlike that Android killed my app?? This way I wouldn't have to go through all the functions my app has and to figure out how to get them work as a service.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that even the foreground service may be killed by the OS so you still have to implement life cycle of your service

Comment: I know but I have understood it's quite unlikely. Anyway, is there any better solution, i.e. is there some mechanism to fully prevent it or some other workaround? And do you agree with my proposal above?

Comment: You solution is the best choice,  your foreground service is the last soldier to be killed on the battlefield of RAM